# JOIN и IN - одинаковый ли будет результат? равны ли запросы?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `blog_post` WHERE `id` IN 
        (
            SELECT id_post FROM `key_post` WHERE `id_tag` IN 
                (
                    SELECT id FROM `tag_post` WHERE `tag` = 'вася'
                )
        ) AND `status` = 1 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0, 30;
```

**и**

```
SELECT * FROM `blog_post`
        LEFT JOIN `key_post` ON `key_post`.`id_post` = `blog_post`.`id`
            LEFT JOIN `tag_post` ON `tag_post`.`id` = `key_post`.`id_tag`
                WHERE `tag_post`.`tag` = 'вася' AND `blog_post`.`status` = 1 ORDER BY `blog_post`.`id` DESC LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Результат будет одинаковым у этих запросов?

Comment: Может да, может нет. Сильно зависит от данных. LEFT JOIN выбирает строки для которых id есть в key_post с добавлением полей из key_post и строки, для которых key_post.id_post не существует. В первом варианте эти строки в выборку не попадут. Так же и с tag_post.

Во втором варианте (ну уже не помню -- sorry) select * from означает толи все поля из blog_post, толи все поля из трёх таблиц. Уточните сами.

Comment: > Результат будет одинаковым у этих запросов?
 таки если у вас таблички под рукой, почему бы самому не попробовать узнать это?

Comment: А что даёт `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`  ?

Answer (score 1):

Запросы будут давать эквивалентные результаты, если во втором запросе выбрать только поля из `blog_post`.

```
SELECT `blog_post`.*
```

Кроме того, для использования `LEFT` нет причины.