# Замена in на join

Tags: долгий-запрос, запрос-в-запросе, mysql

Всем привет! 
Есть запрос:

```
select count(*) as ctr from T1 where my_id in (select my_id from T2 where phrase = 'some_phrase');
```

in работает весьма медленно. 
В SQL запросах я пока не спец, но ясно, что те-же операции можно выполнить используя join.
Объясните, как такое провернуть?

**Update**
Простите народ, я не уточнил - во второй таблице my_id является не первичным ключом. в первой таблице my_id - первичный, а во второй он может встречаться сколь угодно много раз.

Comment: У меня такое чувство, что в этом запросе медленно будет работать отсутствие индекса на phrase.

Я же угадал? Индекса там нет?

Comment: да, phrase - просто поле. Индекс - my_id. ЗАдачи сделать чтоб всё летало - нет, надо просто сделать чтоб это было не совсем уж медленно. Данные идут не пользователю, а в админку для тестов.

Comment: Почитайте [вот это](http://hashcode.ru/questions/199490/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-mysql)

И там уже смотрите что тормозит.

Повторюсь - мне кажется, что тормозит отсутствие индекса на текстовом поле, по которому строите запрос.

JOIN тоже не легкая операция, так что менять IN на JOIN или нет - лично для меня не простой вопрос. Надо смотреть на профилировщик.

Comment: phrase так же может встречаться несколько раз. Такое, вроде, не проиндексируешь?

Comment: @АнТоНиО почему же? Вполне индексируется.

Comment: Проиндексируешь, еще как... Вот только добавление/изменение будет подтормаживать на индексах.

Соответственно здесь выбираете из меньших зол - если добавляете куда реже чем ищите - значит индекс стоит ставить, в противном случае можно и подождать пока запрос отработает свое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS `cnt`
FROM
    `T1`
INNER JOIN
    `T2` ON `T2`.`my_id` = `T1`.`my_id`
WHERE
    `T2`.`phrase` = 'some_phrase'
```

Такой запрос вернет требуемый Вам результат. Предполагаю, что соответствия записей в таблицах 1 к 1, поля которые участвуют в условии ON должны быть проиндексированы.
А вложенные запросы в условии IN части WHERE в MySQL вообще лучше не использовать, т к интерпритатор запросов MySQL не умеет их корректно обрабатывать.

Comment: в Т2 my_id может встречаться несколько раз.

Comment: А теперь подскажите, чем Ваш ответ отличается от ответа @Gorets? Выравниванием и именем поля `cnt`? А, блин, он ещё `where` не написал. Это он зря.

Comment: @alexlz, ну MySQL в конечном счете вроде как все равно приведет запрос товарища Gorets и товарища ice178 к выражению:

    SELECT COUNT(*) AS `cnt`
    FROM `T1`
    INNER JOIN
        `T2`
    WHERE
        `T2.`my_id` = `T1`.`my_id` AND `T2`.`phrase` = 'some_phrase';

Сами посмотрите:

    explain extended _SQL_;
    show warnings;

Хотя да, повторять ответ другого человека не есть хорошо...

Answer (score 1):

В этом конкретном случае таблица T1 не нужна вообще. Вам необходимо подсчитать, сколько разных кодов my_id встречается в таблице T2. Если между T1 и T2 установлена явная связь (т.е. тут нет висячих ссылок), то достаточно запроса 
    SELECT COUNT ( DISTINCT my_id) FROM T2 WHERE phrase = 'some_phrase'

Comment: Если ТС не "упростил" задачу, стоящую перед ним до COUNT(*). Ежели он такое сделал, то Ваш совет -- мимо кассы. Если ему действительно нужно количество -- тогда Вы правы (хрень тип my_id присутствует в T2, но отсутствует в T1 -- не рассматриавем. Хреней может быть много)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.MY_ID = T2.MY_ID AND T2.PHARE = 'some_phrase';
```

не уверен, но..

Comment: Может быть, может быть. А что случится, если T2.MY_ID -- не уникален? И одному T1.MY_ID соответствуют два (и более) T2.MY_ID?

Comment: не знаю, но думаю что ИД - уже подразумевает уникальность, даже если это не первичный ключ

Comment: Полную гарантию дает только крематорий, поэтому ничто не мешает добавить
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T1.my_id) FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.MY_ID = T2.MY_ID AND T2.PHARE = 'some_phrase';

Comment: Простите народ, я не уточнил - во второй таблице му_ид является не первичным ключем. в первой таблице му_ид - первичный, а во второй он может встречаться сколь угодно много раз.

Comment: не вижу проблем, по условиям подходит, DISTINCT не надо

Comment: @Gorets DISTINCT не нужен, если пара my_id/phrase в T2 является уникальной. Иначе результаты запросов могут отличаться.

Comment: @alexlz, нам нужно КОЛИЧЕСТВО чего-то там или УНИКАЛЬНОЕ КОЛИЧЕСТВО?

Comment: @Gorets не знаю, что нужно *нам*, а вот ТС, подозреваю, нужно, чтобы запрос выдавал те же результаты, что и исходный, только быстрее.

По моему мнению, наиболее разумные советы даёт @ВОРОН

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.count(*) AS ctr FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.my_id=t2.my_id WHERE t2.phrase='some_phrase'
```

Если я не напутал, то так.

Comment: Напутали. Будут добавочно сосчитаны строки с MY_ID, отсутствующими в выборке из T2.

Comment: @alexlz т.к. в where участвует условие по t2, то left join превратится в inner, null значения t2.phrase будут отфильтрованы. а по сути, да, left join тут не нужен априори.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov Да. Несколько напутал я. Единственная ошибка, как и в случае INNER JOIN -- неуникальность пар my_id/phrase в T2

Answer (score 0):

вот похожий 
[Вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/192839/mysql-join-%D0%B8-in-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B)

вот только с join  он быстрее не будет

Comment: Практика показывает, что быстрее. Плюс джоины он кеширует сам походу.